# How can I calculate selected checkbox foreach only

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, checkbox

I need to calculate selected checkbox only that foreach in a table field (harga_obat*jumlah)

This is my foreach data

```html
@foreach ($obat as $o)
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kode_obat" value="{{ $o->kode_obat }}" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_obat" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="harga" type="text" class="form-control" name="harga_obat" value="{{ $o->harga_obat }}"
            onkeyup="sum()">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="jumlah" type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlah" onkeyup="sum()">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="total" type="text" class="form-control total-harga" name="total_harga" onkeyup="sum()" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

This is what I have tried, this is just working for one row like picture below

```js
function sum() {
    var harga = document.getElementById('harga').value;
    var jumlah = document.getElementById('jumlah').value;
    var hasil = parseInt(harga) * parseInt(jumlah);
    if (!isNaN(hasil)) {
        document.getElementById('total').value = hasil;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Give same class to all checkbox and you can count using : len = $(".checkBoxClass:checked").length

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple lines to foreach, you cannot rely on unique ids. One (inelegant?) solution could be to define dynamic different ids for each row and pass that id to your `sum` method.

Another solution would be to use a more generic approach that bind the `sum` method to each row, and passing it the parent scope, an only working with the existing ids, like below:

```js
function sum(parent) {
    var harga = parent.querySelector('[name="harga_obat"]').value;
    var jumlah = parent.querySelector('[name="jumlah"]').value;
    var hasil = parseInt(harga) * parseInt(jumlah);
    
    if (!isNaN(hasil)) {
        parent.querySelector('[name="total_harga"]').value = hasil;
    }
}

function bind(el) {
  el.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    sum(event.currentTarget.closest("tr"));
  });
}

document.querySelectorAll('[name="harga_obat"]').forEach(function (element) {
  bind(element);
});
document.querySelectorAll('[name="jumlah"]').forEach(function (element) {
  bind(element);
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kode_obat" value="{{ $o->kode_obat }}" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_obat" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="harga" type="text" class="form-control" name="harga_obat" value="{{ $o->harga_obat }}">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="jumlah" type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlah">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="total" type="text" class="form-control total-harga" name="total_harga" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kode_obat" value="{{ $o->kode_obat }}" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_obat" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="harga" type="text" class="form-control" name="harga_obat" value="{{ $o->harga_obat }}">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="jumlah" type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlah">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="total" type="text" class="form-control total-harga" name="total_harga" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```